# How do I populate a listbox based on a selected item from another listbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have two listboxes(Regions and Divisions) when my form loads the Regions listbox is populated with 4 regions(Midwest, NorthEast, South, West). When I click on one of those regions I want the Divisions listbox to populate with the divisions that relate to the region that was clicked. I am working through a data repository that communicates with my SQL db. 
Initial population upon form load

```
StateRepository sr = new StateRepository();
foreach (string s in sr.GetRegions())
{
    lstRegions.Items.Add(s);
}
```

Code behind the GetRegions method:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetRegions()
{
    try
    {
        List<string> results = new List<string>();
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(Settings.Default.StateAnalysisConnection))
        {
            using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "Select * From Regions ";
                conn.Open();
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        results.Add((string)reader["Region"]);
                    }
                }
            }
         }

         return results;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Database error in StateRepository", ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            connection.Close();
    }
}
```

The method that gets the divisions in region from the db:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetDivisionsInRegion(string region)
{
    try
    {
        List<string> results = new List<string>();
        var divisions = new List<string>();
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(Settings.Default.StateAnalysisConnection))
        {
            using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                 cmd.CommandText = "Select Division From Divisions "
                    + "Where Region = '" + region + "'";
                 conn.Open();
                 using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                 {
                     while (reader.Read())
                     {
                         results.Add((string)reader["Division"]);
                     }
                 }
             }
         }

         return results;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         throw new Exception("Database error in StateRepository", ex);
     }
     finally
     {
         if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
             connection.Close();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of your `Regions` listbox, get the selected region then use that in your `GetDivisionsInRegion` method and populate the `Divisions` listbox with the result.

```
private void Regions_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   // Get the currently selected item in the ListBox. 
   string region = Regions.SelectedItem.ToString();

   // Find the divisions in the region
   IEnumerable<string> divisions = GetDivisionsInRegion(region);

   //set as this as the new data source for your Divisions listbox
   Divisions.DataSource = divisions;
}
```

Although I think you may have to either cast the divisions to `List<string>` or get your `GetDivisionsInRegion` to return a `List<string>`.

Comment: Ok, that worked good and I applied it to a third listbox. But in the third box it uses the ToString() method of my class. So instead of the StateAbberv, I get a brief description of my state. Is there a way around that?

Comment: cast it to your object then use a property (StateAbbrev perhaps?) to get the value that you need.